# Load balance docker swarm

Tags: python, docker, haproxy, docker-swarm

I have a docker swarm mode with one HAProxy container, and 3 python web apps. The container with HAProxy is expose port 80 and should load balance the 3 containers of my app (by `leastconn`).

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  scraper-node:
    image: scraper
    ports:
      - 5000
    volumes:
      - /profiles:/profiles
    command: >
      bash -c "
        cd src;
        gunicorn src.interface:app \
          --bind=0.0.0.0:5000 \
          --workers=1 \
          --threads=1 \
          --timeout 500 \
          --log-level=debug \
      "
    environment:
      - SERVICE_PORTS=5000
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
      update_config:
        parallelism: 5
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
    networks:
      - web

  proxy:
    image: dockercloud/haproxy
    depends_on:
      - scraper-node
    environment:
      - BALANCE=leastconn
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - web

networks:
  web:
    driver: overlay
```

When I deploy this swarm (`docker stack deploy --compose-file=docker-compose.yml scraper`) I get all of my containers:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS          PORTS                       NAMES
245f4bfd1299   scraper:latest       "/docker-entrypoin..."   21 hours ago   Up 19 minutes   80/tcp, 5000/tcp, 8000/tcp  scraper_scraper-node.3.iyi33hv9tikmf6m2wna0cypgp
995aefdb9346   scraper:latest       "/docker-entrypoin..."   21 hours ago   Up 19 minutes   80/tcp, 5000/tcp, 8000/tcp  scraper_scraper-node.2.wem9v2nug8wqos7d97zknuvqb
a51474322583   scraper:latest       "/docker-entrypoin..."   21 hours ago   Up 19 minutes   80/tcp, 5000/tcp, 8000/tcp  scraper_scraper-node.1.0u8q4zn432n7p5gl93ohqio8e
3f97f34678d1   dockercloud/haproxy  "/sbin/tini -- doc..."   21 hours ago   Up 19 minutes   80/tcp, 443/tcp, 1936/tcp   scraper_proxy.1.rng5ysn8v48cs4nxb1atkrz73
```

And when I display the `haproxy` container log it looks like he recognize the 3 python containers:

```
INFO:haproxy:dockercloud/haproxy 1.6.6 is running outside Docker Cloud
INFO:haproxy:Haproxy is running in SwarmMode, loading HAProxy definition through docker api
INFO:haproxy:dockercloud/haproxy PID: 6
INFO:haproxy:=> Add task: Initial start - Swarm Mode
INFO:haproxy:=> Executing task: Initial start - Swarm Mode
INFO:haproxy:==========BEGIN==========
INFO:haproxy:Linked service: scraper_scraper-node
INFO:haproxy:Linked container: scraper_scraper-node.1.0u8q4zn432n7p5gl93ohqio8e, scraper_scraper-node.2.wem9v2nug8wqos7d97zknuvqb, scraper_scraper-node.3.iyi33hv9tikmf6m2wna0cypgp
INFO:haproxy:HAProxy configuration:
global
  log 127.0.0.1 local0
  log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice
  log-send-hostname
  maxconn 4096
  pidfile /var/run/haproxy.pid
  user haproxy
  group haproxy
  daemon
  stats socket /var/run/haproxy.stats level admin
  ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3
  ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA
defaults
  balance leastconn
  log global
  mode http
  option redispatch
  option httplog
  option dontlognull
  option forwardfor
  timeout connect 5000
  timeout client 50000
  timeout server 50000
listen stats
  bind :1936
  mode http
  stats enable
  timeout connect 10s
  timeout client 1m
  timeout server 1m
  stats hide-version
  stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
  stats uri /
  stats auth stats:stats
frontend default_port_80
  bind :80
  reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
  maxconn 4096
  default_backend default_service
backend default_service
  server scraper_scraper-node.1.0u8q4zn432n7p5gl93ohqio8e 10.0.0.5:5000 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 3
  server scraper_scraper-node.2.wem9v2nug8wqos7d97zknuvqb 10.0.0.6:5000 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 3
  server scraper_scraper-node.3.iyi33hv9tikmf6m2wna0cypgp 10.0.0.7:5000 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 3
INFO:haproxy:Launching HAProxy
INFO:haproxy:HAProxy has been launched(PID: 12)
INFO:haproxy:===========END===========
```

But when I try to `GET` to `http://localhost` I get an error message:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>503 Service Unavailable</h1>
    No server is available to handle this request.
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was two problems:

1. The `command` in `docker-compose.yml` file should be one line.
2. The `scraper` image should expose port 5000 (in his `Dockerfile`).

Once I fix those, I deploy this swarm the same way (with `stack`) and the `proxy` container recognize the python containers and was able to load balance between them.

Answer (score 0):

A 503 error usually means a failed health check to the backend server.

Your stats page might be helpful here: if you mouse over the `LastChk` column of one of your DOWN backend servers, HAProxy will give you a vague summary of why that server is DOWN:[image]

It does not look like you configured the health check (`option httpchk`) for your `default_service` backend: can you reach any of your backend servers directly (e.g. `curl --head 10.0.0.5:5000`)? From [the HAProxy documentation](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.5/configuration.html#4.2-option%20httpchk):

> [R]esponses 2xx and 3xx are
>   considered valid, while all other ones indicate a server failure, including
>   the lack of any response.